# Entire View stuck when UIButton is pressed

Tags: ios, swift

I have a good amount of calculation codes get executed when the UIButton is pressed. But when the button is pressed, the whole view just get stuck and the button stay highlighted until the calculation finished.
For example, I set a loading view .hidden = false when the button is pressed too, but the loading view just doesn't show up during the calculation.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post some code so that we can try to help

Comment: Multithreading is the key for smooth UX. Just don't put the calculation in main thread. Once the `UIButton` is pressed, show a loading dialog, launch another thread to calculate, then remove the loading dialog once the calculation is complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have to do the things in background from the updates you want to run on the UI:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
    // do your task

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // update some UI
    }
}
```

Comment: do i put this inside the button action?

Comment: thanks! it works now, but seams like the time of calculation is more than usual? is it normal?

Comment: if you get answer helpful , please upvote it, which will help others .

Comment: @DanielTseng you should accept the answer because it completely solves your problem